# Property inheritance involving objects and prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, prototype

I'm a newbie at JS and in one of my tests I've been trying to figure out how the following code works in terms of property inheritance.

```
function doSomething(){}

doSomething.prototype.foo = "bar"; //Add "foo" property to doSomething's prototype
let anInstance = new doSomething();
anInstance.prop = "value"; //Add "prop" property to object "anInstance"
doSomething.prop = "another value"; //Add "prop" property to "doSomething"
let anotherInstance = new doSomething();

console.log(doSomething.prop);
console.log(anInstance);
console.log(anotherInstance.prop);
```

This is the above script's output in the console:

```
another value

doSomething{prop: "value"}
  prop: "value"
  __proto__:
    foo: "bar"
    constructor: ƒ doSomething()
    __proto__: Object

undefined
```

As you can see, printing `doSomething`'s `prop` property after being added to it returns expected `another value`, but accessing `anotherInstance`'s `prop` returns `undefined`.

Isn't that `anotherInstance` supposed to "inherit" such `prop` property since it's defined within the function from which it was created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a property to a function is not the same as adding a property to the function's prototype object. Instances of the function inherit the function's `prototype` properties, not the function's own properties:

```js
function doSomething(){}

doSomething.prototype.foo = "bar"; //Add "foo" property to doSomething's prototype

doSomething.prop = "another value"; //Add "prop" property to "doSomething" but no the prototype

let anotherInstance = new doSomething();

// only has foo:
console.log(doSomething.prototype)

// this is the object it will inherit from
// only has foo
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherInstance))

//they are the same object:
console.log(doSomething.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(anotherInstance))
```

In the code above `doSomething.prop` is just a property of the function, it plays no role in prototype inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, it's now clearer for me. Yet I still don't get a grasp on why you cannot add a new property _directly_ to a constructor function, as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp) in section _"Adding a Property to a Constructor"_; the explanation given is `"This way object properties can have default values."`. You stated that _only_ prototypes play a role in inheritance. But _why_? Wouldn't it be more easy and straightforward to add a property with a default value to a constructor simply by doing `Constructor.prop = "value"`?

Comment: Yes @JaxLogan - prototype inheritance in javascript has always been unusual and frustrating if you’re coming from a traditional oop language. Many will tell you that ‘inheritance’ isn’t actuall the right name for what JS does. The article you linked is adding props to `this` inside the constructor, not directly to the constructor function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I guess you cannot add a new property to a constructor because you would need `this` to do so, referring to whatever _instance_ is created when calling the function. So you could do `person.newProp = "magic"` because it's an _already created_ object, but for doing something similar with the `Person` constructor you would have to necessarily add `newProperty` to its prototype.